# Bounded linear operator counterexample?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

> Does there exist a continuous linear operator $T: (C[0,1],||.||_2) \to (C[0,1],||. ||_2)$ such that $T$ is discontinuous if $C[0,1]$ is considered with $||.||_\infty$ instead of $||.||_2$ ?

I think that such operator may exist but unable to construct example.Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such operator. Note that $(C ([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_\infty ) $ is a Banach space, so that it suffices to show that $T $ has closed graph.

Thus, assume $f_n \to f $ and $T f_n \to g $ (both with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\infty $).

Then $f_n \to f $ and $T f_n \to g $ bith with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$ (why?) and hence $T f_n \to Tf $ also with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$ by the assumed continuity of $T$.

This shows $g = Tf $ as desired, so that $ T $ is continuous by the closed graph theorem.